# Installing django-jqgrid; strange dependency on Dojango

Tags: jquery, django, jqgrid

Where should I put Dojango's [`util/__init__.py`](http://code.google.com/p/dojango/source/browse/trunk/dojango/util/__init__.py), in order for my code involving [`django-jqgrid`](https://github.com/gerry/django-jqgrid) to work?

Also, how should the JavaScript final file look like? For starters, I suppose it will be in templates?

Comment: The dependency has been removed. I will update the README to both fix the markup and reflect the new changes. Thanks for using django-jqgrid.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed you have updated the readme. When will you put a fully working example with source code in the readme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`django-jqgrid` README](https://github.com/gerry/django-jqgrid) has a markup problem; the bullet point mentioning that `dojango` file *should* look like:

> - [`json_encode`](http://code.google.com/p/dojango/source/browse/trunk/dojango/util/__init__.py#97)

Thus, you need to copy/paste the `json_encode` function (along with all relevant imports) from Dojango's `util/__init__.py`. Looking at [the source of `django-jqgrid`](https://github.com/gerry/django-jqgrid/blob/master/jqgrid.py) shows where that code is expecting to find your pasted function:

```
from util.json import json_encode
```

So either just download `__init__.py` into a `util` directory in your application (*i.e.* the same level as `models.py`) or edit that line in `jqgrid.py` to point to where your `json_encode` function is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess this is questionably accurate / relevant in light of Gerry's answer above, but no -- just download the single `__init__.py` file linked to above, and put it in a folder called "util" in your app.

Comment: al your answers were very clear. everything was well understood. thanks.